# Evaluating an integral using a known integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to evaluate $\int_0^{\pi} e^{\cos t} \cos ( \sin t ) d t $ by considering $\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^z}{z} dz $ where $\gamma $ is the unit circle.

#### Try

Notice

$$ \frac{e^z}{z} = \frac{ e^{\cos t + i \sin t } }{\cos t + i \sin t } = \frac{ e^{\cos t}}{\cos t + i \sin t}(\cos(\sin t) + i \sin (\sin t)) $$

Also, $dz = ( - \sin t + i \cos t ) dt = -\frac{1}{i}(i \sin t + \cos t)dt $

and so

$$ \int_{\gamma} \frac{ e^z dz}{z} = -\frac{1}{i} \int\limits_0^{2 \pi} e^{\cos t}( \cos( \sin t) + i \sin ( \sin t) ) dt $$

But, here is where I got my confusion. The integrand in the right hand side limit is entire, hence it must be zero inside the unit circle. What am I missing?

Comment: $\exp(z)/z$ has a pole at $z=0$.

Comment: For the right hand side, can I write $\int_0^{2 \pi} F(t) dt = 2 \int_0^{\pi} F(t) dt $ ?

Comment: What does it mean that the integrand is entire? The integrand don't even look like a function defined on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: yes, I realize now. Im trying now to compute those integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. As has been pointed out in the comments, it's not clear what you mean by "The right-hand side limit is entire". To finish the calculation, note that the residue of the integrand on the left at $z=0$ is $1$, so the integral on the left is $2\pi\mathrm i$. Then multiplying through by $-\mathrm i$ shows that the integral on the right is $2\pi$. Thus we can drop its imaginary part. The real part of the integrand is invariant under reflection at $\pi$, so the integral you want is half of this integral, and thus evaluates to $\pi$.

Comment: how can the real part has period $\pi$. Im trying to prove but it isnt working.

Comment: @user135395: Do you mean "how can the real part have period $\pi$?", or do you mean "how can I prove that the real part has period $\pi$?"?

Comment: I went through the calculation and I end up getting that the real part doesnt have period $\pi$

Comment: @user135395: My apologies. It doesn't have period $\pi$, it's symmetric about $\pi$ (with the same result). I've corrected the answer. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: no problem. How can I show that it is symmetric about $\pi$ ?

Comment: Do i need to show that $f(\pi - x) = f(x - \pi )$ ?

Comment: @user135395: No, that would be symmetry about $0$. Symmetry about $\pi$ means $f(\pi-x)=f(\pi+x)$, or equivalently $f(x)=f(2\pi-x)$.

Comment: @user135395: Since the integrand also has period $2\pi$, your condition is actually equivalent to mine in this case, but in general it isn't.