How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\cos(x)}\cos(\sin(x))dx$?
Evaluate the following integral $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\cos(x)}\cos(\sin(x))dx$$
First of all I tried by using Integration By Parts. What I found is
$$I=\cos(\sin(x))\int e^{\cos(x)}+$$ $$\int \sin(\sin(x))\cos(x)\int e^{\cos(x)}dx$$
But after this step, I was facing problem in integrating by applying Integration By Parts.
Now my father suggested me to apply the formula $$\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}=\cos(x)$$
Which indicates $$\frac{e^{i\sin(x)}+e^{-i\sin(x)}}{2}=\cos(\sin(x))$$
Now according to my Father's suggestion I found the integral to be $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{\cos(x)+i\sin(x)}+e^{\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}}{2}dx$$
Next step :
$$I= \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{e^{ix}}+e^{e^{-ix}}}{2}dx$$
Now I can't go further.
Do let me know if anyone can solve.

Same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1485469/732917?

Let
$
I(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{a\cos x}\cos(a\sin x)dx\\
$. Then
\begin{align}
I’(a)
=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{a\cos x}\cos(x+a\sin x)dx
= \frac1a e^{a\cos x }\sin(a\sin x)\bigg|_{0}^{\pi} =0
\end{align}
and
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\cos x}\cos(\sin x)dx=I(1)=I(0)=\pi\\
$$

Since the integrand is even and $2\pi$ periodic, we have $2I=\text{Re}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}}dx$. Now try substituting $z=e^{ix}$ and transform the integral into a contour integral. Afterwards the classic machinery of complex analysis should suffice. I will post a full solution if you need further help.

Starting with $2I=\text{Re}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}}dx$, we consider the integral $J=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}}dx$. By the substitution $z=e^{ix}$, we get $dz=i e^{ix}dx$ and $dx=\frac{dz}{iz}$ and $z$ varies in the unit circle reverse clockwise as $x$ varies between $[0,2\pi]$. Thus we obtain
$$J=\frac{1}{i}\oint_{|z|=1} e^{iz}\frac{dz}{z}.$$
By Cauchy's residue theorem, $J$ equals $2\pi$ times sum of residues of the integrand in the circle $|z|=1$. The integrand only has a simple pole at $z=0$. The residue is computed as follows,
$$\underset{z=0}{\text{Res}}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}=\lim_{z\to0} z\frac{e^{iz}}{z}=1.$$
Therefore we have
$$J=2\pi \underset{z=0}{\text{Res}}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}=2\pi.$$
Now finally we get $I=\pi$.

Maybe it's better to include this answer in the first answer you posted
